# How to add user input shapefile as a parameter into "GDB Creator" Python Script tool

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, python-script-tool, nameerror

I created a Python Script tool to create a GDB inside of a user defined folder path.  I am trying to find a way to add another parameter in my script tool for a user to input a shapefile after they created their GDB.  The shapefile would be converted into a feature class and stored inside the user created GDB.  I have been having trouble making a connection between the shapefile the user enters and then storing it inside the geodatabase.

Code:

#Importing Modules/Creating Function

```
import arcpy
import os
```

#Function to create GDB

```
def gdbbuilder(gdbnames):
arcpy.AddMessage("...Starting Function")
  if arcpy.Exsists(currentdir):
        arcpy.Delete_management(currentdir)
  else:
      pass
currentdir =  arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
projectname = currentdir.split("\\")[-1]
for gdbname in gdbnames.split(";"):
    newgdbname= "{}_{}".format(projectname,gdbname)
    arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(currentdir, newgdbname, "Current")
```

#Creating Second & Third User parameter

```
gdbnames = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
inputlyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inputlyr,currentdir)
```

My thought process was that the user could create the gdb first then use the inputlyr(shpfile) and the currentdir(gdb) as parameters for the copy feature function to create a featureclass in that gdb. However, I recieve
`Creating GDB in folder. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Arcpy\GDBcreator.py", line 31, in <module> arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inputlyr,currentdir) NameError: name 'currentdir' is not defined` as the output error.

Comment: I don't think this will cause that error but the code that you've presented has incorrect indentation after your `def` statement.

Comment: You are deleting the existing folder with arcpy.Delete_management(currentdir) but not re-creating it anywhere. Be very careful when using Delete. I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have commented the code below. This will create multiple geodatabases and add the shapefile input to each of them.

```
import arcpy

currentdir = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
gdbnames = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
inputlyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

def gdbbuilder(currentdir, gdbnames, inputlyr):
    arcpy.AddMessage("...Starting Function")

    ## folder name for the project
    projectname = currentdir.split("\\")[-1]
    arcpy.AddMessage(projectname)
    folder_path = currentdir.rsplit("\\", 1)[0]
    arcpy.AddMessage(folder_path)

    ## if the directory already exists, delete it
    if arcpy.Exists(currentdir):
            arcpy.Delete_management(currentdir)

    ## create the folder
    arcpy.CreateFolder_management(folder_path, projectname)

    ## list of gdb names
    gdb_lst = gdbnames.replace("'", "").split(";")

    ## shapefile name without the shp to name the feature class
    ## make sure the feature class is a valid name
    fc_name = inputlyr.split("\\")[-1].replace(".shp", "").replace(" ", "_")

    ## for each gdb in the input gdb list
    for gdbname in gdb_lst:
        ## the name of the gdb to create
        newgdbname = "{0}_{1}".format(projectname,gdbname)
        ## the new gdb path
        gdb_path = "{0}\\{1}.gdb".format(currentdir, newgdbname)

        arcpy.AddMessage("Creating GDB: {0}".format(gdb_path))
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(currentdir, newgdbname)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Converting Shapefile to Feature Class")
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inputlyr, gdb_path, fc_name)

gdbbuilder(currentdir, gdbnames, inputlyr)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @clubdebambos